# Compare rows value in two tables and return if any of value from a row is different

Tags: t-sql

How can I compare rows from two tables and return the row if at least 1 of the values from a column is different.

Table A

```
No   Name   ID   Date       Profile  Status  Age    
1    John   213  12/2/2010   KDS      ONB    32
1    John   213  12/2/2011   KDS      ONB    23
2    John   213  12/2/2012   KDS      ONB    13
1    John   213  12/2/2013   KDS      ONB    14
2    John   213  12/2/2012   KDS      ONB    41
```

Table B

```
No   Name   ID   Date       Profile  Status  Age    
1    John   213  12/2/2010   KDS      ONC    32
1    John   213  12/2/2011   KDS      ONB    23
2    John   213  12/2/2012   KDS      ONB    14
1    John   213  12/2/2013   KDS      ONB    14
2    John   213  12/2/2012   KDD      ONB    41
```

I should get in the table B the following rows:

```
1    John   213  12/2/2010   KDS      ONC    32
2    John   213  12/2/2012   KDS      ONB    14
2    John   213  12/2/2012   KDD      ONB    41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tableB except select * from tableA
```

Comment: did it throw an error? or it didn't produce the desired results?